# Positive and negative correlation -what’s the relationship?-covariance and correlation

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, covariance, correlation

Question - show that if y=ax+b with a>0 then corr(x,y)=1 . What relationship between X and Y would give Cov(x,y)=-1?

I got from subbing in y=ax+b that it is equal to
$$a/√a^2$$
Which I think will give you $$ a/mod a$$

Comment: I'm not sure what 'moda' is but this question seem quite straightforward. You just have to plug into the formula where Corr(X,Y) = Cov(X,Y) / sqrt(Var(X)Var(Y))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=-x+b$  (i.e. $a=-1$), then $Cov(y,x)=corr(y,x)=-1$.